# Azure Linked Server RPC error with Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, linked-list, rpc

I have an Azure database setup as a Linked Server which can be queried fine. I can also execute stored procedures without any issue.

However as soon as I try inserting the results of a stored procedure call into a table I get an RPC failure: -

```
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for remote/network 
transactions.
```

I have set RPC Out to true on the Linked Server properties and have MSDTC running as a service.

To replicate: -

```
exec [AzureLinkedServerName].myAzureDB.dbo.usp_MyStoredProc
```

Runs without error and returns a list of email addresses.

```
DECLARE @res TABLE (id INT IDENTITY (1,1), email nvarchar(255))

INSERT INTO @res
        ( email )
exec [AzureLinkedServerName].myAzureDB.dbo.usp_MyStoredProc
```

Fails with the RPC error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had neglected to set Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions (linked server properties) to false.